Calculate order end date based on date and number of weeks ACF fields
We have 3 ACF fields added to Woocommerce orders - start date (pick_up_date), number of weeks (number_of_weeks) and end date (end_date)
Start date and number of weeks are manually entered and the value of the end date field should be calculated based on those 2 values (start date + (7*number_of_weeks) = end date) and correct formatted (d/m/Y), then saved in the end_date field
I have trouble working with the date fields to have the end date calculated correctly. I'd appreciate your help it getting this to work

This seems to have worked
function UpdateEndDate($post_id){
    
//get start date and number of weeks
$start_date = get_field('pick_up_date',$post_id);
$weeks = get_field('number_of_weeks',$post_id);

// Create and modify the date.
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $start_date);
$dateTime->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString($weeks . ' weeks'));
$end_date_final = $dateTime->format('d/m/Y');

    
update_field('end_date',$end_date_final,$post_id); 
    
}
add_action('acf/save_post', 'UpdateEndDate', 20); 


You could consider working with unix timestamps (a numerical representation of a date and time that is the seconds elapsed since 00:00:00 1st January 1970). This makes the math easier since we would be working with plain numbers:
// Convert pick up date to unix timestamp integer.
$start_timestamp = strtotime( get_field( 'pick_up_date' ) . ' 00:00:00' );

// Get the number of weeks as seconds:
// 60 - seconds in a minute, minutes in an hour.
// 24 - hours in a day.
//  7 - days in a week.
$weeks_in_seconds = get_field( 'number_of_weeks' ) * 7 * 24 * 60 * 60;

// Add the weeks period of time to our start timestamp.
$end_timestamp = $start_timestamp = $weeks_in_seconds;

// Convert our result timestamp back to a date string.
$end_date = gmdate( 'd/m/Y', $end_timestamp );


Thanks, looks like a good approach, will test it shortly. How should I save the calculated end_date value to the ACF field we already have in place for woocommerce orders?

You could consider using the update_field() function.

I have put together this function and the end date field was update, but with the vale of 01/01/1970

Consider checking get_field( 'pick_up_date' ) (or equivalent) returns a string that can be interpreted by strtotime(), get_field( 'number_of_weeks' ) (or equivalent) returns an integer.
